# Nested React Router won't render

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a popup component overlaying the main content that I want to render through routing, but because I want it to build on existing routes without messing up my main page configuration, I have tried going for a nested route. However, I seem to have misunderstood how it is supposed to be done. I wrapped the export with "withRouter" and tried to do this:

```
 <Fragment>
     <Helmet>
         <title>Videos - Saddex Productions</title>
     </Helmet>
     <Switch>
         <Route path="/popup"
         render={() => <Popup items={props.videos}/>}
         />
      </Switch>
      ...
```

This doesn't work and only renders the main component. And I also don't want to outsource the code that's going to be rendered underneath, because it seems unneccessary. However, what should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you navigate to the /popup url when you render this component?

Comment: I do. It doesn't simply work, and I don't get why really. FYI, the parent component is which I may have implied part of a router itself. That one does work.

Comment: Solved: The reason it didn't work is because I presumed the router works like the Express router does - with relative paths. I included the base path like "videos/popup" and now it works, it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:** The reason it didn't work is because I presumed the router works like the Express router does - with relative paths. I included the base path like "videos/popup" and now it works, it seems.